# Is a difference in the implementation of boost::asio between Unix(AIX, HP-UX) and Linux(RedHat, Ubuntu)?

Tags: boost-asio

In Windows the Completion Event Queue is implemented by the operating system, and is associated with an I/O completion port.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html

But what of this (select, epoll or kqueue) used for maximum perfomance on Unix and what on Linux, and is there a difference in the implementation of boost::asio between Unix(AIX, HP-UX) and Linux(RedHat, Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [platform specific implementation notes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/implementation.html) describes the supported platforms and how the event demultiplexing is implemented. Newer Linux kernels will use [`epoll(4)`](http://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll) while older versions use [`select(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select). AIX and HP-UX both use [`select(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select).

[`kqueue(2)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kqueue&sektion=2) is used on BSD systems, including Mac OS X and iOS. It is very similar to `epoll` on Linux.

Generally speaking, `epoll` will perform better than `select`. When using `select`, it performs a linear search over the list of `n` descriptors, this is `O(n`). Using epoll has the concept of an `epoll_event` structure when adding descriptors to the epoll descriptor. This means modifying the list of events to wait for is somewhat expensive, but waiting for these events is very fast at `O(1)`.

Comment: Thanks! But why not use IO Completion Port on AIX? http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc%2Fdoc%2Ft0054518.html

Comment: @Alex the `select` interface works on nearly all platforms, I'll guess the Asio author has limited access to AIX development resources. Feel free to submit a patch.

Comment: But why didn't put into new standards of POSIX an unified optimized method of demultiplexing with same interface and behavior like as (EPOLL/KQUEUE/POLL_SET)?